# Errors when running sosumi in kali (Qemu)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, qemu

I installed sosumi in a kali linux VM (Virtualbox) but when i run sosumi to launch the emulator i get these errors:

```js
*** Launch!
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.fma [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi1 [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.smep [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsaveopt [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsavec [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xgetbv1 [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.fma [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi1 [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.smep [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsaveopt [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsavec [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xgetbv1 [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.fma [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi1 [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.smep [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsaveopt [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsavec [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xgetbv1 [bit 2]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.fma [bit 12]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi1 [bit 3]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.smep [bit 7]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.07H:EBX.bmi2 [bit 8]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsaveopt [bit 0]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xsavec [bit 1]
qemu-system-x86_64: warning: host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.0DH:EAX.xgetbv1 [bit 2]
qemu_gl_create_compile_shader: compile vertex error
0:2(10): error: GLSL ES 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES

qemu_gl_create_compile_shader: compile fragment error
0:2(10): error: GLSL ES 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES

qemu_gl_create_compile_shader: compile vertex error
0:2(10): error: GLSL ES 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES

qemu_gl_create_compile_shader: compile fragment error
0:2(10): error: GLSL ES 3.00 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, and 1.00 ES
```

here https://snapcraft.io/sosumi it states that after installation, i can just run sosumi and it should boot to the macOS recovery system but instead i'm getting these errors.

Comment: What you want to do requires **nested virtualization** support.

Comment: I already have it enabled.

Comment: If so then it's not supported.